# Вывести одну запись самую просматриваемую за 24 часа

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `video`. в ней поле `view` (количество просмотров).
Нужно вывести одну запись самую просматриваемую за 24 часа.
Подскажите как организовать?
Создать отдельную таблицу `views_video` и туда сохранять `id_video` и время просмотра?

Comment: Опишите, как у вас работает трэкинг просмотров для видео. Т.е. как обновляется поле `view` и сохраняются ли данные о факте просмотра (в частоности дата и время)?

Comment: сейчас все работает лишь как update view = view  + 1 без фиксации времени

Comment: Тогда предложенный вами вариант с таблицей `view_video` и сохранением даты и времени просмотра будет вполне работоспособным. Единственное предостережение - запрос за самым популярным в течении 24-х последних часов видео будет относительно трудозатратным: join + group by + sort. Поэтому, если он планируется использоваться довольно часто, то есть смысл поискать другое решение.

Comment: спасибо...может кто и подскажет другое решение в этой теме

Comment: > 4% принятых

и 

> может кто и подскажет другое решение в этой теме

врядли

Answer (score 2):

А вот я бы ни в коем случае не последовал совету уважаемого [@Shad](/users/1560/shad). Мой совет - создайте еще таблицу с двумя полями: id_video(вторичный ключ) и дата-время_просмотра. И Ваш запрос не будет иметь проблем.

Comment: дата-время_просмотра - хранить выгодно в timestamp? потом как определить диапазон 24 часа?

Comment: Ну я специально сделал оговорку, когда такой подход иммет смысл: при частом вызове целевого запроса и огомном количестве данных о просмотрах. Более того, видел такой подход, примененный на практике в high-load системе (правда, использвался MS SQL Server)

Comment: @IOleg, диапазон в 24 часа - через "between"

Comment: Поддержу @BuilderC! Но я бы сразу сделал такую таблицу viedo_views (id (PK), user_id (FK), video_id (FK), datetime). Это позволит и выбирать самую просматриваемую запись за 24 часа, и количество просмотров как в разрезе видео, так и в разрезе пользователя. А также у каждого пользователя, например, отобразить самые просматриваемые или последние просмотры.

Наличие истории для такого сервиса просто необходимо (потом можно любые выборки построить).

Answer (score 0):

Если запрос за самым популярным в течении 24-х последних часов видео будет использоваться довольно часто, то есть смысл **рассчитывать заранее** количество просмотров за прошлые 24 часа. Для этого нужно будет добавить новую таблицу `views_video` (вы сами верно описали её в вопросе) и колонку в таблицу `video` - например, `view_24hours`, в которой будет храниться количество просмотров за последние 24 часа. Такой подход избавит от необходимости группировки данных при каждом таком запросе. Подсчеты просмотров можно делать периодически в фоновом режиме (например 1 раз в час или реже - все зависит от ваших нужд, возможностей сервера и объема данных). Логика процедуры подсчета просмотров за 24 часа будет примерно такой:

- выбрать из таблицы `views_video` все просмотры за прошлые 24 часа
- сгруппировать их по `video_id`
- обновить колонку `view_24hours` в таблице `video` в соответсвии с подсчитанными значениями
- для видео, которое не попало в выборку установить `views_24hours` в `0`.

Такая периодичесий пересчет в фоновом режиме упростит требуемый запрос. Вам останется лишь отсортировать по полю `views_24hours` по невозрастанию и взять первую запись. Недостатки: периодические повышения нагрузки на сервер в результате таких пересчетов, и небольшая потеря в актуальности информации, так как данные о просмотрах видео за прошлые 24 часа меняются не в реальном времени, а через заданные промежутки времени.